# Java renameTo problems

Tags: java

I have the following code to move files which fails:

```
public static void someFunction() {
     Util.moveFile(new File("C:\\Users\\zumdamam\\workspace\\CareerBuilder\\data\\careerbuilder\\Java.html"), new File("C:\\temp\\Java.html"));
}

public static void moveFile(File src, File dest) {
        try {
            if (src.renameTo(dest)){
                System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
            } else{
                System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

if the parameter is changed to

```
C:\\Users\\zumdamam\\workspace\\CareerBuilder\\data\\Java.html
```

Then it works. Any one has any clue why it is behaving so?

Thanks

Comment: sounds like permissions

Comment: We cannot help you without the cause why it fails (exception, error message?) and just seeing your path. Maybe you should provide some information.

Comment: How exactly it fails? Do you have any exception?

Comment: So usually you have to make sure the parent directory and the entire directory hierarchy is intact for the destination File. So in your case you have to make sure C:\temp is created. File tempDir = new File("C:\\temp"); if (!tempDir.exists() || !tempDir.isDirectory()) { tempDir.mkdirs();} then do your move. It also could be permissions sadly. A boolean returned is not helpful I know :(

Comment: Fails means can't copy. It goes directly to the else block and prints "File is failed to move!". Besides, I can manually copy paste (control+x, control+v) so it is not a permission problem either.

Comment: Dou you actually mean that the case of the filenames messes the move up? Like vels4j's answer says: This depends on your platform and/or filesystem.

Comment: Sorry now I understood the problem. I have a method call in an Util class which I have been using for a long time for various projects in the past without giving any indication of problem. In that method I read the content of a file. But I didn't close the reader object used to read the file. Now when I am calling this method and then trying to delete the file later on - the file delete was not working. The FileUtils method which I thought worked, worked unpredictably giving the wrong impression of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [File.renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method in java Doc

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently
>   platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a
>   file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it
>   might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname
>   already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure
>   that the rename operation was successful.

You could use apache's [FileUtils.moveFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#moveFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Comment: It is interesting since FileUtils.moveFile is using File.renameTo

Answer (score 0):

These are the reasons that come to my mind (on a windows-machine):

1. The sourc-file doesn't exist.
2. The target-directory doesn't exist (it is not created automatically).
3. The target-filename already exists
4. You don't have permission to write to the target-directory

Answer (score 0):

Of course. '\' is special character in java String (for example \n is new line or \u041f is some Unicode character). If you want to use '\' itself you should to put '\\' inside of your String